# Group Days based on matching hours

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

How might I code a function in PHP to merge days with similar opening hours of a store together. For example, if we have:

```
Mon  : 9:00AM - 7:00PM
Tue  : 9:00AM - 10:00PM
Wed  : 9:00AM - 7:00PM
Thu  : 9:00AM - 10:00PM
Fri  : 9:00AM - 7:00PM
Sat  : 9:00AM - 10:00PM
Sun  : 9:00AM - 7:00PM
```

I want the code output as:

```
Mon,Wed,Fri,Sun - 9:00AM - 7:00PM
Tue,Thu,Sat - 9:00AM - 10:00PM
```

Below is the code which I'm trying to work out.

```
$openHours = array(
    'Mon' => '9am-7pm',
    'Tue' => '9am-10pm',
    'Wed' => '9am-7pm',
    'Thu' => '9am-10pm',
    'Fri' => '9am-7pm',
    'Sat' => '9am-10pm',
    'Sun' => '9am-7pm'
);

$summary = array();
foreach ($openHours as $day => $hours) {
    if (!array_key_exists($hours, $summary))
        $summary[$hours] = array($day);
    else
        $summary[$hours][] = $day;
}

foreach ($summary as $hours => $days) {
    echo array_shift($days) . '-' . array_pop($days) . ' ' . $hours . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I found the similar article but it is not outputting the correct output.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906984/combine-days-where-opening-hours-are-similar)

Comment: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123 for pointing me to the article. I have edited the question again hope now the question makes sense.

Comment: Please also show us from where you get the input? As a file, json, string, array, .. ? And also add your current code/attempt to solve the problem to the question.

Comment: From your first posted question to the current state you made a huge improvement! Most times you can ask a question in this simple structure: "I  get A and want to get D out of it, I try this with B, but I get C, how can I get to D?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

First we change the array structure and use the time as key and the days as values with this code:

```
foreach($openHours as $k => $v)
    $array[$v][] = $k;
```

So we end up with an array structure like this:

```
Array
(
    [9am-7pm] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mon
            [1] => Wed
            [2] => Fri
            [3] => Sun
        )

    [9am-10pm] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tue
            [1] => Thu
            [2] => Sat
        )

)
```

After that we just need to loop through the new array and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the days to a string separated by a comma and append the time after it.

Code:

```
<?php

    $openHours = array(
        'Mon' => '9am-7pm',
        'Tue' => '9am-10pm',
        'Wed' => '9am-7pm',
        'Thu' => '9am-10pm',
        'Fri' => '9am-7pm',
        'Sat' => '9am-10pm',
        'Sun' => '9am-7pm'
    );


    foreach($openHours as $k => $v)
        $array[$v][] = $k;

    foreach($array as $time => $days)
        echo implode(",", $days) . " " . $time . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

output:

```
Mon,Wed,Fri,Sun 9am-7pm
Tue,Thu,Sat 9am-10pm
```

Answer (score -2):

> $closetime = ['7:00'=>['Mon','Wed','Fri','Sun'],
>   '10:00'=>['Tue','Thu','Sat']];
>
> foreach ($closetime as $time => $days) {   echo explode(',', $days)."
>   - 9:00 - ".$time; }

or something like that

Comment: You should try to understand the question.

Comment: @AliZia when I answered the question only the first 2 paragraph of the question was there. I answered the question as it was originally asked.